# OnListItemClick(...) is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android

I have created a ListView from an Adapter, but I would like to select items, that gives an information about this item in new Activity.

That's my code:

```
        protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView listview, 
                                            View view, int pos, long id)
    {
        var selectedvalue = sw_items[pos];
        var i = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
        i.PutExtra("selectedvalue", selectedvalue);
        StartActivity(i);
    }
```

But i get this error:

```
MainActivity.OnListItemClick(Android.Widget.ListView, Android.Views.View, int, long)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override (CS0115)
```

MainActivity is an `Activity`

How can I solve this problem or is there any other way to do this within `Activity`

Comment: you should read some books about C# ... does `MainActivity` base class have method `OnListItemClick`?

Comment: but I used this method in my previous project and it worked. And MainActivity is only the name of my Activity.

Comment: heh what is the base class for `MainActivity` ? and search for answer for: when to use `override`? do we need to use `override` when we implementing interface in C#?

Comment: Does your `MainActivity` class inherit from `Activity` or `ListActivity`?

Comment: Oh, I noticed I used ListActivity in my previous project. Have somebody an idea how to solve this within Activity?

Comment: Is your `MainActivity` inherited from `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the override, then somewhere in your setup you need to hook your method up to the click event on your list.

Normally this is done like this:

```
myList.OnClick += new ClickEventHandler(myMethodName);
```

But I haven't used monodroid so there may be some slight nuances.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this. Because of this: The type or namespace name `ClickEventHandler' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? (CS0246).

Comment: I removed the override, the error is gone but if I select an item nothing happens. :(

Comment: Yes, you need to find the right event handler for the type of object you are using (ListView)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override `OnListItemClick` in `MainActivity`, the activity must be inhereited from `ListActivity` instead of plain old `Activity`.

Also, make sure the `Listview` in your xml is with the id "@android:id/list" (or `list` if it's in code).

There is a really nice guide you can follow: [Populating a ListView With Data](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
@Override
protected void OnListClick(ListView listview, View view, int pos, long id) {
    var selectedvalue = sw_items[pos];
    var i = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
    i.PutExtra("selectedvalue", selectedvalue);
    StartActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: never mind, just noticed your using c#, not java. This probably won't work.